# Checkbox Post Array Empty

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong with this array.  I've tried everything but it is always coming up empty in my post.

Greatly appreciated, Paul.

FORM

```
while ($rowcat2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultcat2)) { 
        $accSubcatID = $rowcat2["id"];
        $accvalue = $rowcat2["value"];

    <span><?=$accvalue?>:</span><input type="checkbox" name="accSubcat[]" id="accSubcat[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="<?=$accSubcatID?>" />

}
```

POST DATA

```
  if(!empty($_POST['accSubcat'])){

    foreach($_POST['accSubcat'] as $key) {

        $accsubcatID = $key;

        if ($accsubcatID) {

    $sql3= "INSERT INTO yt_acc_data (busID,subcatID)
    VALUES ('$busID','$accsubcatID')";
    //Execute SQL statement

        if(!($mysql_rs3 = mysql_query($sql3)))
        die("Error in executing query3");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `id="accSubcat[]"` is wrong. HTML IDs are unique to each DOM element. You either want a `class` property (in which case drop the `[]`) or you don't need this at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tomalak suggest a good point

now  first i say u must check

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($)POST);
```

if post array coming properly then , i just optimize your mysql/php way, have a look

*btw* what is **$mysql_rs3** with that u r comparing the mysql statement in `if` condition??

```
if(!empty($_POST['accSubcat'])){
    foreach($_POST['accSubcat'] as $key=>$value) 
    {
     if (!empty($value)) {
        // i think datatype of *busID* and *subcatID* is integer
        $sql3= "INSERT INTO yt_acc_data (busID,subcatID) VALUES ($busID,$accsubcatID)";
        //Execute SQL statement         
        if(!(mysql_query($sql3)))
            die("Error in executing query3");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, makes sense.  That works much better.  I just had to add in $value instead of the $accsubcatID.  The $mysql_rs3 was fine to take out.